Find $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{4^i}$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^2}{4^i}$$

This is not a geometric series, nor any other kind of progression. But, from Ratio-test i was able to establish that this is convergent. Also from a simulation in Excel up to n=511, i found that this is converging at around 0.740741

Hint Consider $f(x) = \sum i^2 x^i$ at $x=1/4$.  Determine some combination of derivatives or integals of $f$ that is a geometric series.

Thanks a lot!
If i use $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{i^2}{x^i} = \frac{-x(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$ at $x=\frac{1}{4}$,
i get $f(x)=\frac{\frac{-1}{4}(\frac{5}{4})}{(\frac{-3}{4})^3}=\frac{\frac{-5}{1}}{\frac{-27}{4}}$
which simplifies to $f(x)=\frac{20}{27}$ indeed equal to $0.\bar{740}$
